# VSCode reconhecer código PHP em arquivos "include"

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Estou usando o VSCode no Windows para programar em PHP.
Porém ao usar o require_once (ou include_once), o VSCode marca como erro as chamadas de métodos declarados nas classes do arquivo onde eu chamo os outros.
Exemplo:

> index.php

```
use Src\Funcoes;

require_once('arquivo.php');
```

> arquivo.php

```
$objeto = new Funcoes(); // Aqui o VSCode marca como erro
```

O código funciona, mas no VSCode é exibido como erro. Tem alguma configuração que eu possa fazer? Estou usando a extensão *PHP Intelephense* no VSCode.

Comment: Mesmo que funcione, o VScode está certo em apontar o erro, vc deve importar `Src\Funcoes`  nos arquivos que vc utiliza.

Comment: Entendi, André. Mas se pelo menos o VSCode/Intelephense puder reconhecer que estou dando include desse arquivo no principal, me ajudaria. Não sei se é uma boa prática, mas vou manter a pergunta em aberto. Vou ajustar o fonte para a sua sugestão, se aparecer alguma resposta que solucione, beleza. Obrigado pela atenção!